# SvelteKit routes, return multiple content types for end-points (XML, JSON, TEXT, etc.)

Tags: sveltekit

Giving svelte-kit a test run and trying to create an end-points that can return `JSON` or `XML`. Depending on the request.

I want my URL's to look like this.

```
http://localhost/api/mydata.json
http://localhost/api/mydata.xml
```

The routes in svelte would than look like this:

```
src
  routes
    api
      mydata.xml
        +server.js
      mydata.json
        +server.js
```

Essentially you create 2 folders (mydata.xml and mydata.json) one for each mimetype. This works.

Hoever, Is it possible to keep the same URL but merge both endpoint into a single folder ?

Something among the lines of this:

```
src
  routes
    api
      mydata
        +server.xml.js     <= this doesn't work
        +server.json.js.   <= this doesn't work
```

I'm sure as an alternative you could move the mime-types into a subfolder of `mydata`. Bu then the ULR's woud slighty change.

```
// routes
// http://localhost/api/mydata/xml
// http://localhost/api/mydata/json
src
  routes
    api
      mydata
        xml
          +server.js
        json
          +server.js
```

And there is also a solution where you would specify the mime-type you meed via a query paramater. And solve this via some simple logic.

```
http://localhost/api/mydata?type=json
http://localhost/api/mydata?type=xml

...
```

However, I would like to know if you can solve it by separating the code in 2 separate files.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parameters you can diversify the response based on the parameter

```js
// /src/routes/api/mydata.[type]/+server.js
export const GET = async ({ params }) => {
  const result = { };

  switch (params.type) {
    case 'xml':
      return xml(result);
    case 'json':
    default:
      return json(result);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter to the path:

```
src/routes/api/mydata.[type]/+server.js
```

```js
export const GET = ({ params }) => {
    // params.type
}
```

If you want separate files, you can then delegate from there.
There is no way to have *only two* files in the same directory to my knowledge.